# Why is this rotation matrix giving the opposite direction as expected?

Tags: python, matrix, vector

As a simulation of the reflection of light, I created a vector plot as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def norm(x): 
    return np.sqrt(x.dot(x))

def angle_between_vectors(v1, v2):
    return np.arccos((v1.dot(v2)) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2)))

def vector_from_angle(theta, normal):
    # counterclockwise rotation matrix
    rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], 
                                [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return np.matmul(-normal, rotation_matrix)

# incoming light ray vector
v_i = np.array([4, 3])

# incoming light ray origin
v_i_origin = np.array([0, 0])

# normal vector of (not shown) surface light ray reflects off of
normal = np.array([1, -0.3])
normal_origin = np.array([4, 3])

angle = angle_between_vectors(v_i, normal)
outgoing = vector_from_angle(angle, normal)

origins = np.array([v_i_origin, normal_origin, normal_origin, normal_origin])
vectors = np.array([v_i, normal, -2 * normal, outgoing])

plt.quiver(origins[:, 0], origins[:, 1], vectors[:, 0], vectors[:, 1], color=["r", "g", "b", "m"], angles="xy", scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

This resulted in the following image:

[image: Vectors plot]

Where the incoming vector is the red vector, normal vector is the green vector, and outgoing vector the purple vector.

However, the direction of the outgoing (purple) vector confuses me, as I used a counterclockwise rotation matrix:

```
cos(θ) -sin(θ)
sin(θ)  cos(θ)
```

Thus, I would expect the `vector_from_angle()` function to give the flipped normal vector, rotated counterclockwise, like so:

[image: Vector from angle annotated]

So why does the vector point in the correct direction with a clockwise rotation even though I am using a counterclockwise rotation matrix?